# Mysqli while dont show all rows

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I got an problem, PHP while dont show all rows from database if I do it on DESC it shows all but not last one if I use ASC it shows all but not first one. I tryed many solutions but none worked yet.

Please help me at this code:

```
$sql1 = " SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC";

if ($result1 = $mysqli->query($sql1)) {
    $news = $result1->fetch_array();
} 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
echo "<p><b> {$row['name']} </b><br />";
echo "{$row['text']} <br />";
echo "<font size='2'>{$row['date']}</font></p>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're fetching the first row and assigning it to `$news`.  This means that it's already been fetched when you begin your loop.  Remove that line and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this     and bring your while loop inside the if statement.

```
$sql1 = " SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC";

if ($result1 = $mysqli->query($sql1)) {
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
echo "<p><b> {$row['name']} </b><br />";
echo "{$row['text']} <br />";
echo "<font size='2'>{$row['date']}</font></p>";
    }
}
```

Cause you already fething the first result.
`$news = $result1->fetch_array();` **remove this line,** 
so thats why it does not show you the first result, when you use ASC, 
and it wont show you the result when you use DSC.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $sql1 = " SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
        echo "<p><b> {$row['name']} </b><br />";
        echo "{$row['text']} <br />";
        echo "<font size='2'>{$row['date']}</font></p>";
    }
```

when $news = $result1->fetch_array(); this line executes, it already fetch the first result into $news variable. As a result you loose the first record from your record set.